# Limit how many posts can be set to Featured

Tags: wordpress, admin, taxonomy, wordpress-featured-image

This is an odd question. It's been requested by a client but I'm having trouble finding any examples of it being done before so I'm mostly just looking for any hint or trail to follow to make this work.

I have a wordpress site built with a featured post taxonomy. The home page is set to only display six featured posts, and by default it displays them in the order they were posted.

What the client wants is for there to be some sort of functionality that limits how many posts can be set as featured at any given time. So an example of how this ideally would work would be there are six featured posts, the admin goes in and sets a new post as featured. As a result, the post that was least recently set as featured would be automatically removed from the featured posts category, ensuring that there are only six  ever set at any time.

So to try to summarize that in a sentence, they want some sort of functionality built that will automatically remove the least recent featured post from that category so that they do not have to do so themselves.

I'm having trouble finding any example of this having been done before, if anyone has done something similar or knows where I can start learning to build this functionality, that would be a lot of help. I hope I was able to describe what they are looking for clearly enough.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Featured Posts is not part of WordPress core so it would be your theme that is handling the featured post code.

Without knowing what your theme is I can't really be of specific help.

Off the top of my head, create a featured post array, use count() to keep track of the number of items in the array. Use if statments with array_unshift() to add to the front of the array and array_pop() to remove a post from the back of the array when it exceeds the max number of featured posts.

Here is a post that might give you an idea of how it can be accomplished.
http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/wordpress-featured-content/

Contacting support for the creator of your theme is also a good option.

Comment: The theme was Underscores, and the featured option was created through a custom taxonomy, if that helps. Thank you for the link, I'll definitely read up and try to start finding a solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is not that easy as the featured post feature is not built for that. However I suggest the following:

Pseudo-code:

```
// On save post check if the post is featured

// If the post is featured get the number of featured posts from the database

// if the number of featured posts from the database including the current post is greater than six un-feature the post with the oldest timestamp
```

This code is not tested but it should work similarly:

```
add_action('save_post','ensure_only_6_stickies');

function ensure_only_6_stickies($post_id) {

  if(is_sticky($post_id)) {
    $stickies = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );

    if(is_array($stickies) && !in_array($post_id,$stickies) && count($stickies)>=6) {
      $stickies = array_slice($stickies,5);
      array_push($post_id,$stickies);
      update_option('sticky_posts',$stickies);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The featured option is made through a custom taxonomy so I'm not sure if that'll effect how this code works or not, but the logic here definitely has me a step closer to figuring something out.

Comment: Ah well I thought you was talking of stickies. However The concept should be pretty similar. On save_post check how much posts are featured and if its > 6 kick the oldest out.